# Appcelerator Titanium Alloy | Sliding menu creation like facebook and (for android and ios both)

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I am learning appcelerator titanium and want to create sliding menu like facebook and gmail.

I have found a [widget](https://github.com/mcongrove/com.mcongrove.slideMenu) and have followed every documented step but my application got stuck in splash screen.

Can anyone please help to get rid of it?

Comment: Why don't you create an issue on github? You'll need to provide some code.

Comment: Any code or error logs will be helpful.. I personally use this one https://github.com/danielsefton/AlloySliderMenu, you could give it a try if you still keep having issues

Comment: @Naliza does above module work for android too?

Comment: @Naliza i am not getting any error.

Comment: @AbdulAleemAkhund yes.. it supports both ios and android.. more info here http://www.danielsefton.com/2013/05/slider-menu-widget-v2-for-titanium-alloy/

Comment: @Naliza thanks for your quick response. it says the project has an invalid/non-platform GUID and can  not be run, please register the app with the platform, which will udpate it's GUID

Comment: @AbdulAleemAkhund Which sdk version are you using?

Comment: @Naliza i am using the latest SDK 5.0G

Comment: @AbdulAleemAkhund Ok,that might be the reason why then..my apologies.  I am actually updating my studio/sdk right now so I'll see if I get the same issue.

Comment: @nazila. Sure. please update me, if you get any solution. thanks!

Comment: @AbdulAleemAkhund hey, I've updated my sdk and everything works fine. I did encounter that message - you just have to go to your tiapp.xml and register your app

Comment: @Naliza can you please tell me how to register app?

Comment: @AbdulAleemAkhund in your tiapp.xml  (in the overview section). You should see a 'Register' button. I'm using the new appcelerator studio, not sure if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

@AbdulAleemAkhund: You can use this widget [nl.fokkezb.drawer](https://github.com/FokkeZB/nl.fokkezb.drawer) which is the best solution for your problem. And it is from the most famous guy in Appcelerator community Fokke Zandbergen. Furthermore, you can find other awesome widgets in this side [gitt.io](http://gitt.io/).